# how to run parallel processing Pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, pyomo

**Background**

I am trying to solve a MILP problem using pyomo with a 'cbc' solver. the optimisation problem is being run over time series data and is very large (3005 rows, 3011 columns (2010 with objective) and 15998 elements)

**What I am attempting to do**

I've read that 'cbc' supports parallel processing. I've tried to implement it, but without luck. I've got the latest 'cbc' binaries.

**What I've tried**

```
# Solve the model
opt = SolverFactory('cbc')
opt.options['threads'] = 16
opt.options['parallel'] = True
instance = model.create_instance("scenario1.dat")
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
instance.solutions.load_from(results)
```

however, CPU usage remaining flat and low, and in the log it seems to not even recognise the options.['parallel'] command.

```
command line - C:\cbc-win64\cbc.exe -sec 100 -timeMode elapsed -threads 16 -parallel True -printingOptions all -import C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfpy0lgal.pyomo.lp -stat=1 -solve -solu C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfpy0lgal.pyomo.soln (default strategy 1)
seconds was changed from 1e+100 to 100
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
threads was changed from 0 to 16
No match for parallel - ? for list of commands
No match for True - ? for list of commands
```

**Help Requested**

- Does any one know what I am doing it wrong,
- could it be that I am misunderstanding what pyomo multiprocessing does (i.e. as I am trying to solve one big complex problem, and not just run the solver over multiple multiple independent solvers in parallel).

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things may help...

1. `pyomo` is not multi-threaded ...  All that `pyomo` does is create the model, which is done be executing good old python code to create the model.  The time to do this is usually trivial compared to solve times, so there is nothing to be gained--for all practical purposes--by applying any multi-processing here.
2. Assuming you are using the most recent version of `cbc` which as of this post is 2.10.8, you can pass in the `threads` option as you are doing and it will be used *when* the solver gets to the branch & bound portion of the solving process.  It may be the case that there is a significant amount of time in pre-solve, which is all a single-threaded process.  If you watching the Activity Monitor (Mac) or whatever Windows has to offer, you will probably see the `cbc` threads bounce up to whatever you specify *when* the branch & bound starts and stay there through the remainder of the solve, which may be minutes, hours, days....
3. I don't think `parallel` is a recognized `cbc` option nor is it recognized.